# Why would I have to continually reset my hot tubs heater?

Tags: heater, hot-tub

Trying to determine if I have a heater issue or maybe a sensor problem. Heater works and heats up the 2000 Grandee hot tub, but every few days it stops working. If I turn if off at breakers for a few minutes, and then press the reset button, it will begin heating again. So any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We inherited a a hot tub with a house purchase, it was probably 10 years old. After a few months of use, it would sometimes trip the GFCI breaker during use.

I opened the access panel on the hot tub and opened up the control box and the heater unit itself had some corrosion hear the pressure switch.

I removed the corroded heater and replaced it with an aftermarket heater, like the one below. This solved my GFCI problem.  FYI, you'd need to buy the pressure switch separately, heavy gauge wire, and be comfortable installing such a device yourself. Or, buy it and hire an electrician to install it.

[image: Universal replacement heater]

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the previous answer corrosion can create a high amp draw by reducing the voltage, a loose electrical connection does the same thing, it will get hot and eventually burn out, safety devices like breakers or manually resettable high limit switches are not helped by being tripped numerous times,it  can damage causing nuisance tripping after a defective component is replaced or an electrical connection is tightened or repaired.